# Div Background Picture

Tags: html, css, background

I'm having trouble positioning my background image in css. I finally got the image to be positioned the way I want with help from another question on here. However, now the picture is repeating even though I called the "no-repeat" background function.

```css
.pic{
 position: absolute;
 right: 50%;
 width:50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-repeat: no repeat;
 background-image: url("Twitter_Bird.svg.png");
 background-position: 150px;
 background-color: #1c94e0;
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a typo there ? ( `background-repeat: no repeat;`)

try writing no-repeat